# Shopify liquid - get products by string

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have the slug of a collection. And I know that I can get the products of a collection by slug by doing:

```
collections.this-is-my-slug.products
```

However I have this slug as string assigned to a variable called collection_slug.

If I write:

```
collections.collection_slug.products
```

It does not work. As the string does not get put into there...

How can I solve this?

Here is the code:

```
{% assign collection_url = block.settings.collection_url | split: '/' %}
{% assign collection_slug = collection_url.last %}

{% for product in collections.collection_slug.products %}
    product
{% endfor %}
```

**SOLVED IT BY:**

```
{% for collection in collections %}
 {% if collection.url == block.settings.collection_url %}
    {% for product in collection.products %}
     ...
```

Answer (score 3):

A better solutions is to just use square brackets.

`collections[collection_slug].products` this will work.

When you say `collections.collection_slug` you say "Get me a collection with a handle/slug called collection_slug".

But when you say `collections[collection_slug]`you say "Get me a collection with the variable collection_slug"